# Validating Input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm working on a web form with several textboxes and a submit button. When the submit button is clicked, I am supposed to verify that the required fields all have input and that the age field is only numeric. For example, the user can enter 56, but 56 years-old, shouldn't be accepted. If the user enters invalid input or leaves required fields blank, the border around the appropriate textboxes should turn red.

However, as my code is written now all the required fields turn red regardless of input. Any ideas how I can fix this and make the page follow the couple of rules I listed?

**Most Recent Code**

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Project 4</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
        background-color: black;
        color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px double blue;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to my Web Form!</h1>
        <p>
        Please fill out the following information.<br>
        Please note that fields marked with an asterisk (*) are required.
        </p>
            <form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            *Last Name: <br>
            <input type="text" id="lastname">
            <br>
            First Name: <br>
            <input type="text" id="firstname">
            <br>
            *Hobbies (separate each hobby with a comma): <br>
            <input type="text" id="hobbies">
            <br>
            Pets: 
            <div id="petsContainer">
            <input type="text" id="pets"> 
            <input type="button" id="addPet" value="Add Pet">
            </div>
            <br>
            Children: 
            <div id="childContainer">
            <input type="text" id="children">
            <input type="button" id="addKid" value="Add Child">
            </div>
            <br>
            *Address: <br>
            <input type="text" id="address">
            <br>
                *Phone Number:<br>
            <input type="text" id="phone">
                <br>
            *Age: <br>
            <input type="text" id="age">
            <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var validatePhoneOnKeyUpAttached = false;
            var validateLNameOnKeyUpAttached = false;
            var validateHobbiesOnKeyUpAttached = false;
            var validateAddressOnKeyUpAttached = false;
            var validateAgeOnKeyUpAttached = false;

                function validateForm() {
                        if(!validatePhoneOnKeyUpAttached) {
                            document.getElementById("phone").onkeyup = checkPhone;
                            validatePhoneOnKeyUpAttached = true;
                        }
                else if(!validateLNameOnKeyUpAttached) {
                    document.getElementById("lastname").onkeyup = checkEmpty;
                    validateLNameOnKeyUpAttached = true;
                }
                else if(!validateHobbiesOnKeyUpAttached) {
                    document.getElementById("hobbies").onkeyup = checkEmpty;
                    validateHobbiesOnKeyUpAttached = true;
                }
                else if(!validateAddressOnKeyUpAttached) {
                    document.getElementById("address").onkeyup = checkEmpty;
                    validateAddressOnKeyUpAttached = true;
                }
                else if(!validateAgeOnKeyUpAttached) {
                    document.getElementById("age").onkeyup = checkEmpty;
                    document.getElementById("age").onkeyup = checkAge;
                    validateAgeOnKeyUpAttached = true;
                }

                        return checkEmpty() && checkPhone() && checkAge();
                }

                function checkPhone() {
                        var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
                        var phoneNum = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
                        if(phoneNum.length > 6 && phoneNum.length < 11) {   
                            document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor="transparent";
                            return true;
                    } 
                        else if(phoneNum.length < 7 || phoneNum.length > 10) {
                            document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor="red";
                            return false;
                        }
                }

            function checkEmpty() {
                var lname = document.forms["myForm"]["lastname"].value;
                var pNum = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
                var hobs = document.forms["myForm"]["hobbies"].value;
                var live = document.forms["myForm"]["address"].value;
                var yr = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
                document.getElementById("lastname").style.borderColor = (lname == "") ? "red" : "transparent";
                document.getElementById("hobbies").style.borderColor = (hobs == "") ? "red" : "transparent";
                document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor = (pNum == "") ? "red" : "transparent";
                document.getElementById("address").style.borderColor = (live == "") ? "red" : "transparent";
                document.getElementById("age").style.borderColor = (yr == "") ? "red" : "transparent";
            }

            function checkAge() {
                var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
                if(isNan(age)) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("age").style.borderColor="red";
                    return true;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("addPet").onclick=function() {
                var div = document.getElementById("petsContainer");
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                        input.name = "pats[]";
                div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                div.appendChild(input);
            }

            document.getElementById("addKid").onclick=function() {
                var div = document.getElementById("childContainer");
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                        input.name = "child[]";
                div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                div.appendChild(input);
            }

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm currently having is that when I click the submit button, all the fields turn red for a split second, but then go back to the regular color and the input is erased. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Black-Hole, how to fix my code so it performs the validations on input correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By including all of the borderColor="red" statements in a single code block, you're applying that style to all your inputs, even if only one of them failed validation. You need to separate out each statement so that it only applies to the individual field(s) that failed validation:

```
document.getElementById("lastname").style.borderColor = (lname == "") ? "red" : "transparent";
document.getElementById("phone").style.borderColor = (pNum == "") ? "red" : "transparent";
...
```

Also, I'm using the ternary operator `? :` to clean up the code as well. These statements would replace the if-else block you've written.

Comment: Hi,l used this to fix my code, but am having one problem, when I click the submit button, all the fields turn red whether or not they have input and then go right back to the regular color and the input is erased. I have updated the fiddle to reflect this. http://jsfiddle.net/jmaxu6un/3/

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following javascript functions in order to validate my form variables. Hope these will helpful for you.

```
var W3CDOM = (document.getElementsByTagName && document.createElement);
window.onload = function () {
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () {
        return validate()
    }
}
function validate() {
    validForm = true;
    firstError = null;
    errorstring = '';
    var x = document.forms[0].elements;
    for (var i = 0;i < x.length;i++) {
        if (!x[i].value) {
            validForm = false;
            writeError(x[i], 'This field is required');
        }
    }
 // This can be used to validate input type Email values
    /* if (x['email'].value.indexOf('@') == -1) {
                    validForm = false;
                    writeError(x['email'],'This is not a valid email address');
            }
            */
    if (!W3CDOM)
        alert(errorstring);
    if (firstError)
        firstError.focus();
    return validForm;
}
function writeError(obj, message) {
    validForm = false;
    //if (obj.hasError) return false;
    if (W3CDOM) {
        obj.className += ' error';
        obj.onchange = removeError;
        var sp = document.createElement('span');
        sp.className = 'error';
        sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        obj.parentNode.appendChild(sp);
        obj.hasError = sp;
    } else {
        errorstring += obj.name + ': ' + message + '\n';
        obj.hasError = true;
    }

    if (!firstError)
        firstError = obj;
    return false;
}
function removeError() {
    this.className = this.className.substring(0, this.className.lastIndexOf(' '));
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this.hasError);
    this.hasError = null;
    this.onchange = null;
}
```

You can call the validations right after the form submission as given below.

```
<form name="loginForm" action="do.login" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validate();">
```